# linux kernel module memory checker

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module

I'm developing a kernel memory checker to find memory leaks in kernel space.

1. I have two functions profile_vmalloc and profile_vfree, profile_vmalloc uses vmalloc to allocate memory and adds memory allocated info to a list, profile_vfree frees the allocated memory and removes that info from the list. How to replace vmalloc and vfree so that when I compile and run my module any kernel module allocating and freeing memory will use my functions ?
2. How do I use sysfs to create a read only file that will allow the user to see a summary of memory leaks?

This is what my code looks like so far

```
// Linux Kernel headers
#include    <linux/module.h>
#include    <linux/kernel.h>
#include    <linux/init.h>
#include    <linux/config.h>
#include    <linux/vmalloc.h>

#define  FILE_NAME_LENGTH          256
#define  vmalloc(size)              profile_malloc (block_size, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define  vfree(mem_ref)                 profile_free(mem_ref)

struct _MEM_INFO
{
    const void          *address;
    size_t              size;
    char                file_name[FILE_NAME_LENGTH];
    size_t              length;
};
typedef struct _MEM_INFO MEM_INFO;

struct _MEM_LEAK {
    MEM_INFO mem_info;
    struct _MEM_LEAK * next;
};
typedef struct _MEM_LEAK MEM_LEAK;



#undef      vmalloc
#undef      vfree


static MEM_PROFILER_LIST * ptr_start = NULL;
static MEM_PROFILER_LIST * ptr_next =  NULL;

/*
 * adds allocated memory info. into the list
 *
 */
void add(MEM_INFO alloc_info)
{

    MEM_PROFILER_LIST * mem_leak_info = NULL;
    mem_leak_info = (MEM_PROFILER_LIST *) malloc (sizeof(MEM_PROFILER_LIST));
    mem_leak_info->mem_info.address = alloc_info.address;
    mem_leak_info->mem_info.size = alloc_info.size;
    strcpy(mem_leak_info->mem_info.file_name, alloc_info.file_name); 
    mem_leak_info->mem_info.line = alloc_info.line;
    mem_leak_info->next = NULL;

    if (ptr_start == NULL)  
    {
        ptr_start = mem_leak_info;
        ptr_next = ptr_start;
    }
    else {
        ptr_next->next = mem_leak_info;
        ptr_next = ptr_next->next;              
    }

}

/*
 * remove memory info. from the list
 *
 */
void erase(unsigned pos)
{

    unsigned int i = 0;
    MEM_PROFILER_LIST * alloc_info, * temp;

    if(pos == 0)
    {
        MEM_PROFILER_LIST * temp = ptr_start;
        ptr_start = ptr_start->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    else 
    {
        for(i = 0, alloc_info = ptr_start; i < pos; 
            alloc_info = alloc_info->next, ++i)
        {
            if(pos == i + 1)
            {
                temp = alloc_info->next;
                alloc_info->next =  temp->next;
                free(temp);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
 * deletes all the elements from the list
 */
void clear()
{
    MEM_PROFILER_LIST * temp = ptr_start;
    MEM_PROFILER_LIST * alloc_info = ptr_start;

    while(alloc_info != NULL) 
    {
        alloc_info = alloc_info->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = alloc_info;
    }
}

/*
 * profile of vmalloc
 */
void * profile_vmalloc (unsigned int size, const char * file, unsigned int line)
{
    void * ptr = vmalloc (size);
    if (ptr != NULL) 
    {
        add_mem_info(ptr, size, file, line);
    }
    return ptr;
}


/*
 * profile of free
 */
void profile_free(void * mem_ref)
{
    remove_mem_info(mem_ref);
    free(mem_ref);
}

/*
 * gets the allocated memory info and adds it to a list
 *
 */
void add_mem_info (void * mem_ref, unsigned int size,  const char * file, unsigned int line)
{
    MEM_INFO mem_alloc_info;

    /* fill up the structure with all info */
    memset( &mem_alloc_info, 0, sizeof ( mem_alloc_info ) );
    mem_alloc_info.address  = mem_ref;
    mem_alloc_info.size = size;
    strncpy(mem_alloc_info.file_name, file, FILE_NAME_LENGTH);
    mem_alloc_info.line = line;

    /* add the above info to a list */
    add(mem_alloc_info);
}

/*
 * if the allocated memory info is part of the list, removes it
 *
 */
void remove_mem_info (void * mem_ref)
{
    unsigned int i;
    MEM_PROFILER_LIST  * leak_info = ptr_start;

    /* check if allocate memory is in our list */
    for(i = 0; leak_info != NULL; ++i, leak_info = leak_info->next)
    {
        if ( leak_info->mem_info.address == mem_ref )
        {
            erase ( i );
            break;
        }
    }
}

/*
 * writes a memory leak summary to a file
 */
void mem_leak_summary(void)
{
    unsigned int i;
    MEM_PROFILER_LIST * mem_output;

    FILE * fp_write = fopen (SUMMARY_FILE, "wt");
    char info[1024];

    if(fp_write != NULL)
    {

        fwrite(info, (strlen(info) + 1) , 1, fp_write);
        sprintf(info, "%s\n", "-----------------------------------");   
        fwrite(info, (strlen(info) + 1) , 1, fp_write);

        for(mem_output= ptr_start; mem_output!= NULL; mem_output= mem_output->next)
        {
            sprintf(info, "address : %d\n", leak_info->mem_output.address);
            fwrite(info, (strlen(info) + 1) , 1, fp_write);
            sprintf(info, "size    : %d bytes\n", leak_info->mem_output.size);          
            fwrite(info, (strlen(info) + 1) , 1, fp_write);
            sprintf(info, "line    : %d\n", leak_info->mem_output.line);
            fwrite(info, (strlen(info) + 1) , 1, fp_write);
            sprintf(info, "%s\n", "-----------------------------------");   
            fwrite(info, (strlen(info) + 1) , 1, fp_write);
        }
    }   
    clear();
}

static int __init profiler_init(void)
{
    return 0;
}

static void __exit profiler_cleanup(void)
{
    printk("profiler module uninstalled\n");
}

module_init(profiler_init);
module_exit(profiler_cleanup);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: Ask on http://kernelnewbies.org/

Answer (score 0):

> How to replace vmalloc and vfree so
>   that when I compile and run my module any kernel module allocating and
>   freeing memory will use my functions ?

**Step 1.** In the files that call `vmalloc` & `vfree`, define macros:

```
 #define vmalloc(x) profile_vmalloc(x)
 #define vfree(x) profile_vfree(x)
```

This will ensure that your functions are called.

**Step 2:** In your definition of the `profile_*` functions, do you accounting and call the actual `vmalloc/vfree` functions.

You are already doing the step 2, so you just need to take care of step 1.

Comment: Thanks for the help with step 1, I think that will solve my problem, but I'm still having a problem with step 2, the way I'm attempting to write to file in my code would probably work in user space but no in kernel space, could you help me out with that?